# Cloudfoundry command line tool doesn't push all files

Tags: php, cloud-foundry, buildpack, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to push a simple application to IBMBluemix (Cloudfoundry) but some files are not picket up.

I have a folder containing some files (index.php, test.html, ...). All these are pushed, but my css folder for example is not.

In the root folder containing these files and folders I type:

```
cf push -m 128M -b https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-php-build-pack.git testname
```

So after this

```
testname.mybluemix.net/index.php
```

is accessible, but

```
testname.mybluemix.net/css/reveal.min.cs
```

is not.

Any ideas?

Best Regards

Romeo

Comment: A couple suggestions. a.) Run `cf files <app> app/htdocs/` and see what's there.  Maybe it uploaded but it is not available through the web for some reason  b.) Look in your current folder, see if there's a `.cfignore` file, that can cause the client to skip uploading files.  If you cloned a project from somewhere, this might exist.  c.) Check file permissions on the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot! The problem was not files not being pushed. The buildpack I specified just ignored them. Changing the buildpack solved the issue. But I've learned about .cfignore and the -p parameter so the discussion was worth it.

Comment: Can you post what buildpack you used so if others encounter this issue they have the answer as well?

Comment: This one didn't work: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/staticfile-buildpack

Answer (score 3):

When you push your app make sure you are in the root directory of your app. (ex. /Users/jsmith/dev/myapp.  Make sure you are in the folder that has your index.php file.  Also check to make sure there isn't a .cfignore file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the -p parameter to let the cli know where your application is living?

for example if my app is located on my Desktop I would cd to my desktop and do something like this

```
cf push testname1 -m 128m -b https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-php-build-pack.git -p myApp
```